# ArgumentError on initialize with Rack::SslEnforcer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I am getting an argument error when trying to use rack-ssl-enforcer.
The error is coming from the initialize! call in environment.rb.

I am using the version at https://github.com/pelle/rack-ssl-enforcer

In application.rb:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => ["/login", "/logout", /^\/static\//, "/"]
  end
end
```

Stack trace as follows:

```
/Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) (ArgumentError)
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `new'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `build'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:208:in `inject'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `each'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `inject'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in `build_middleware_stack'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/rails/tuteon-rails/trunk/tuteon/config/environment.rb:5
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/rails/tuteon-rails/trunk/tuteon/config.ru:3
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/ruby/gems/.bundler/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/rails/tuteon-rails/trunk/tuteon/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /Users/adamwilson/work/rails/tuteon-rails/trunk/tuteon/config.ru:1
```

Comment: Did you put that in environment or application.rb?

Comment: It was in application.rb .. updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's because your regex isn't wrapped in a `%r{}`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that it's not evaluating properly as a function call without the parens.  Try:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.middleware.use(Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => ["/login", "/logout", /^\/static\//, "/"])
  end
end
```

Seems like a long shot.  The syntax looks valid and follows the examples from the SslEnforced README, can't imagine why it's giving you that error other than being picky about parens and somehow misinterpreting the options hash.

Comment: Thanks - however I still get the error upon starting the server.

Comment: Did you check what version of the 'rack' gem you have installed?  It seems like your Rack::Middleware API is different than expected.